# cannot convert a java project into a dynamic project, where is the Project Facets button?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Juno, Tomcat 7. I cannot add my project to the server, it always said: there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server.
I tried to solve it by changing the .project file, following the instruction here http://greatwebguy.com/programming/eclipse/converting-a-java-project-to-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse/

However there's no Project Facets button shown when Project Properties dialog is shown, pls see attached screenshot. [image] What am I missing? thanks

PS: I'm aware this was asked, but my problem hasn't been solved following the steps listed in there
[Converting a Java Project to a Dynamic Web Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838707/converting-a-java-project-to-a-dynamic-web-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't see your `test-app` as a project. So far, it is just a folder under `Tomcat v7.0 Server`.

Did create the project in Eclipse originally? Then you can make it a project (in the Eclipse sense) again by importing it: *File -> Import -> (General) -> Existing project into Workspace*. Then select the root folder containing the `.project` file.

Otherwise, you have to create a new Java project and add the existing source and configuration files.

In either case, when you have your project in the workspace, you can select it, choose *Project -> Properties* and then you can edit its facets.

Comment: The project test-app was a zip file I grabbed from a tutorial.
I created a brand-new project, then manually added the files. The Project Facets now shows. Tks