# how to convert java project into java ee project

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, jframe, japplet

I have a java project that contains a JFrame, I need to convert this project into eclipse for java ee project, and convert this JFrame into JApplet, so that I can easily embed the JApplet in jsp code. Please tell me how do I do it?

I am using:
   **Eclipse kepler standard for Java Project** and **Eclipse for Java EE developers** for running an applet/webapplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838707/converting-a-java-project-to-a-dynamic-web-project

Comment: Thank you dear... It's similar. I try to go through it. Thanks again :-)

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). What does this applet/application do that cannot be done in pure HTML/JS?